# How can I get delimiters in mccli output in Shell

Tags: shell, awk, sed

In trying to process the output of "mccli activity show" (for example), the output might be like this:

```
ID               Status                   Error Code Start Time           Elapsed     End Time             Type             Progress Bytes    New Bytes    

---------------- ------------------------ ---------- -------------------- ----------- -------------------- ---------------- ----------------- ---------    

9133910640004809 Completed w/Exception(s) 10020      2012-06-07 18:00 EDT 00h:53m:46s 2012-06-07 18:53 EDT Scheduled Backup 215   0.2%

9133914600006909 Completed                0          2012-06-08 05:00 EDT 00h:00m:04s 2012-06-08 05:00 EDT Scheduled Backup 0                 0%
```

Desired Output

```
ID,               Status,                   Error Code, Start Time          ,Elapsed     ,End Time             ,Type             ,Progress Bytes    ,New Bytes    

----------------,------------------------, ---------- ,--------------------, -----------, --------------------, ---------------- ,----------------- ,---------    

9133910640004809, Completed w/Exception(s), 10020,      2012-06-07 18:00 EDT, 00h:53m:46s ,2012-06-07 18:53 EDT, Scheduled Backup,  215 ,  0.2%

9133914600006909, Completed ,               0,          ,2012-06-08 05:00 EDT, 00h:00m:04s ,2012-06-08 05:00 EDT, Scheduled Backup, 0 ,                0%
```

Code I Tried

```
awk '!/---/{$1=x; sub(/,+$/,x)}1' OFS=,
```

but its not working as its putting comma for every space

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. Do you want to insert commas with leading or trailing space?

Comment: I just want to separate the column using a comma. I tried doing it using space as a delimiter but it's not working, so I want to separate them based on patter --- ---

Comment: Why is there a `,` between `215` and `0.2%`?

Comment: 215 is the Progress bytes where 0.2 % is the new Bytes so there should be a comma between them.

Comment: I want a comma for all the lines separated by ----  ----- this pattern

Answer (score 1):

You posted expected output doesn't really make sense (e.g. 2 commas for one apparent field at `0,          ,` and sometimes you have blanks before the comma, sometimes after it, and sometimes before AND after it) and I think your sample input isn't accurate (e.g. `215` and `0.2%` appears too close together) so I'm guessing but - using GNU awk for `FIEDWIDTHS` and `nextfile`, this may be what you really want to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR {
    if ( /^[- ]+$/ ) {
        wids = length($1)
        for ( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            wids = wids " " length(FS $i)
        }
        nf = NF
        nextfile
    }
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    FIELDWIDTHS = wids
    OFS = ","
    $0 = $0
}
NF { $nf = $nf }
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
ID              , Status                  , Error Code, Start Time          , Elapsed    , End Time            , Type            , Progress Bytes   , New Bytes

----------------, ------------------------, ----------, --------------------, -----------, --------------------, ----------------, -----------------, ---------

9133910640004809, Completed w/Exception(s), 10020     , 2012-06-07 18:00 EDT, 00h:53m:46s, 2012-06-07 18:53 EDT, Scheduled Backup, 215   0.2%,

9133914600006909, Completed               , 0         , 2012-06-08 05:00 EDT, 00h:00m:04s, 2012-06-08 05:00 EDT, Scheduled Backup, 0                , 0%
```

or:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR {
    if ( /^[- ]+$/ ) {
        wids = length($1)
        for ( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            wids = wids " " length(FS $i)
        }
        nf = NF
        nextfile
    }
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    FIELDWIDTHS = wids
    OFS = ","
    $0 = $0
}
NF {
    $nf = $nf
    $0 = gensub(/( +),/,",\\1","g")
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
ID,               Status,                   Error Code, Start Time,           Elapsed,     End Time,             Type,             Progress Bytes,    New Bytes

----------------, ------------------------, ----------, --------------------, -----------, --------------------, ----------------, -----------------, ---------

9133910640004809, Completed w/Exception(s), 10020,      2012-06-07 18:00 EDT, 00h:53m:46s, 2012-06-07 18:53 EDT, Scheduled Backup, 215   0.2%,

9133914600006909, Completed,                0,          2012-06-08 05:00 EDT, 00h:00m:04s, 2012-06-08 05:00 EDT, Scheduled Backup, 0,                 0%
```

Comment: It is correct as 0 is the Progress bytes and 0% is the new Bytes. similarly in the case of 215 is the Progress bytes where 0.2 % is the new Bytes so there should be a comma between them

Comment: My first comment was about the `0` under `Error Code`, not under `Progress bytes`. As for the other 2 - they're not aligned that way in your input, the `0.2%` is under the `Progress bytes` header, same as `215` is.. Either your input is fixed width fields or it isn't - it can't change field by field and line by line to sometimes be fixed width and sometimes space separated (while having spaces in some fields) or we can't help you write a tool to parse it.

Comment: Yes.  I agree. Both the output and input are not aligned. I get it In the same way actually.

Comment: Isn't the expected output something **you** provided? If the input could be anything and the output could be anything then you can't write a script to parse that input and produce that output.